# How to read an unconventional Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Any ideas how to read this complicated excel file into a pandas DataFrame?

[image: table]

I have tried this:

```
jpm = pd.read_excel("Downloads/JPM2022_05_06.xlsx",  header=10, usecols='B:P')
```

But I get this error:

```
C:\Users\JWeinstein\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22400\1993557830.py:1: FutureWarning: Defining usecols with out of bounds indices is deprecated and will raise a ParserError in a future version.
```

And my output is a DataFrame with columns named `Unnamed: 1` up through 10 and filled with `NaN` values.
The output dataframe should look something like this, so a lot of additional manipulation required once I get past the reading in step. For example, I need to fill in the correct agency and transpose the months into rows.

```
    SRC agency coup vin     Cbal       Month    CPR         Pred_Month
0   JPM FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   December 5.418937   2022-12-01
1   JPM FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   January  5.549916   2023-01-01
2   JPM FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   February 5.238943   2023-02-01
3   JPM FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   December 5.514456   2022-12-01
4   JPM FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   January  5.550490   2023-01-01
```

Comment: It looks to me like the header is in (0-indexed) row 11, not 10. You might also be interested in the `skiprows` and `nrows` parameters described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: Care to share the file? What's the expected output dataframe?

Comment: Sure, how do I share the file? And I will add an example of the output df as well.

Comment: Added an example of a desired output dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try these two steps:
1.Go to your copy of Excel file and at the top left clickthe menu, FILE>>save as CSV and get its CSV copy
2.If you are using Jupyter notebook, Save your Data file in the Python>> Python310>> Scripts and then try opening it as pd.read_csv("file_name")

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this and report back.

Comment: That definitely helps, but it's still a little wonky